# AngularJS date filter is adding unexpected timezone offset?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/q6KPNejv52SzewDlvGyu?p=preview

Code snippet below:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.message = "It works!";
    $scope.dateStart = new Date();
    
    $interval(function() {
      $scope.dateNow = new Date();
    }, 42)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{ message }} <br>
    
    {{ dateNow - dateStart | date: 'hh:mm:ss:sss' }} <br>
    
    {{ dateNow - dateStart | date: 'hh:mm:ss:sss' : 'UTC' }} <br>
    
</div>
```

- No timezone - displays `01` as hour.
- Passing `UTC` as timezone - displays `12` as hour.

In my other project I figured this workaround... It feels crap, I don't want to copy-paste crap code. Surely there is a better way?

*(maybe I should just use moment, bundle size does not matter that much here)*

```
app.filter('mydate', function(){
  return function(text, extra) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39209842/775359
    var date = new Date(text)
    var userTimezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    var newdate = new Date(date.getTime() + userTimezoneOffset);

    return pad(newdate.getHours(),2) + ":" + pad(newdate.getMinutes(),2) + ":" + pad(newdate.getSeconds(),2) 
           + (extra ? ":" + pad(newdate.getMilliseconds(), 3) : "");
  };
});

app.filter('pad', [function(){
  return function(text, width) { 
    return pad(text, width)
  };
}]);

function pad(text, width) { 
  text = text + ''; // converting to string because if we pass number it will fail
  return text.length >= width ? text : new Array(width - text.length + 1).join('0') + text;
};
```

---

Not a solution: [AngularJS global Date timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841413/angularjs-global-date-timezone-offset) (setting GMT as default still displays it as 12 hours)

Potential duplicate: [AngularJs filter date adding 2 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49048978/angularjs-filter-date-adding-2-hours) (not answered)

Comment: Guess problem here is that (date1 - date2) is no longer date. So you cannot use date filter for it.

Comment: Like you said, your life will be so much easier using moment.js :-)

Comment: I love moment.js already: `$scope.dateInMinutes = moment.duration( moment($scope.dateNow).diff($scope.dateStart) ).asMinutes();`  - so easy, so expressive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `date: 'HH:mm:ss:sss' : 'UTC'` Using capitol HH:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.message = "It works!";
    $scope.dateStart = new Date().valueOf();
    
    $interval(function() {
      $scope.dateNow = new Date().valueOf();
    }, 42)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{ message }} <br>
    
    {{ dateNow - dateStart | date: 'HH:mm:ss:sss' : 'UTC' }} <br>
    
</div>
```

The format string can be composed of the following elements:

- 'HH': Hour in day, padded (00-23)
- 'H': Hour in day (0-23)
- 'hh': Hour in AM/PM, padded (01-12)
- 'h': Hour in AM/PM, (1-12)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `date` Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Comment: Thank you Cpt. Obvious! OMG... Can I have my hours back... That's the nature of the development, a silly issue that can absorb quite a lot of resources.